# Firebase CompareTo Method

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i am trying to use compareTo method based on firebase docs to get how long ago was the database entry created.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/Timestamp

I am trying to do something like this

```
var postedAgo = myEntry.dateCreated.compareTo(firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
```

myEntry.dateCreated is stored TIMESTAMP, so all i got in my db is numerical value. I hope thats right. But the problem is when i log this it says that compareTo is not a function.

I am obviously doing something wrong, but i cant find almost anything on compareTo beyond the documentation. I wonder if anyone is even using it.

Thanks
Luke

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase Database `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` is not an actual value of a timestamp, but a so-called marker value that the server recognized (and then replaces by the current timestamp when writing to the database). Because of this, you cannot use `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` in pure client-side operations.

If you want to determine how long ago a node was created, you'd take the timestamp from that node and subtract it from the current timestamp. So if `myEntry.dateCreated` is a timestamp that was *written* with `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP`, you could do:

```
System.currentTimeMillis() - myEntry.dateCreated
```